# Any tips on how to rig this little robot?

Tags: rigging

I just wanted some opinions on how to rig this robot if it isn't too much! I mean, as you can see from the picture my rigging is terrible, and I'm kinda lost

Don't know how to make any of its parts move without feeling "organic" and having the whole body twisted, unlike that of an actual robot.

If anyone needs the original model just ask me so we can solve this out.

[image]

Comment: so it looks like it is already parented? what kind of problem do you meet?

Comment: For mechanical objects that don't deform, recommend bone parenting. That is parent each part to its pose bone and don't use the armature modifier.